# Google pick location for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, location, google-developer-tools

I read [this](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start) and tried to build a location picker app, where the below code worked perfectly:

```
import UIKit
import GooglePlacePicker

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  // Add a pair of UILabels in Interface Builder, and connect the outlets to these variables.
  @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var addressLabel: UILabel!

  // Add a UIButton in Interface Builder, and connect the action to this function.
  @IBAction func pickPlace(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.788204, longitude: -122.411937)
    let northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: center.latitude + 0.001, longitude: center.longitude + 0.001)
    let southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: center.latitude - 0.001, longitude: center.longitude - 0.001)
    let viewport = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: northEast, coordinate: southWest)
    let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: viewport)
    let placePicker = GMSPlacePicker(config: config)

    placePicker.pickPlace(callback: {(place, error) -> Void in
      if let error = error {
        print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
      }

      if let place = place {
        self.nameLabel.text = place.name
        self.addressLabel.text = place.formattedAddress?.components(separatedBy: ", ")
          .joined(separator: "\n")
      } else {
        self.nameLabel.text = "No place selected"
        self.addressLabel.text = ""
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Apparently the `GMSPlacePicker` is deprecated, and replaced by `GMSPlacePickerViewController`, so I tried the example [here](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/placepicker):

```
import UIKit
import GooglePlacePicker

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  // Add a pair of UILabels in Interface Builder, and connect the outlets to these variables.
  @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var addressLabel: UILabel!
// The code snippet below shows how to create and display a GMSPlacePickerViewController.
@IBAction func pickPlace(_ sender: UIButton) {
  let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: nil)
  let placePicker = GMSPlacePickerViewController(config: config)

  present(placePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// To receive the results from the place picker 'self' will need to conform to
// GMSPlacePickerViewControllerDelegate and implement this code.
func placePicker(_ viewController: GMSPlacePickerViewController, didPick place: GMSPlace) {
  // Dismiss the place picker, as it cannot dismiss itself.
  viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

  print("Place name \(place.name)")
  print("Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
  print("Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
}

func placePickerDidCancel(_ viewController: GMSPlacePickerViewController) {
  // Dismiss the place picker, as it cannot dismiss itself.
  viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

  print("No place selected")
}
}
```

But it is not functioning properly, am I missing anything here? The location picker is poping up, but neither the cancel button is clickable, nor the location picker is closed upon picking the required location, and accordingly nothing is printed!

Comment: you're probably forgetting to set the delegate.

Comment: @tassinari I added `placePicker.delegate = self as? GMSPlacePickerViewControllerDelegate` but nothing changed

Comment: You also need to have your class declare that it implements the protocol : `class ViewController: UIViewController , GMSPlacePickerViewControllerDelegate `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments from @tassinai below the full working code:

```
import UIKit
import GooglePlacePicker

class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSPlacePickerViewControllerDelegate  {
    @IBOutlet weak var placeNameLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func placePicker(_ sender: Any) {
        let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: nil)
        let placePicker = GMSPlacePickerViewController(config: config)

        placePicker.delegate = self

        present(placePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func placePicker(_ viewController: GMSPlacePickerViewController, didPick place: GMSPlace) {
        viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Place name \(place.name)")
        placeNameLabel.text = place.name
    }

    func placePicker(_ viewController: GMSPlacePickerViewController, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    // In your own app you should handle this better, but for the demo we are just going to log
    // a message.
         NSLog("An error occurred while picking a place: \(error)")
    }

    func placePickerDidCancel(_ viewController: GMSPlacePickerViewController) {
        // Dismiss the place picker, as it cannot dismiss itself.
        viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        print("No place selected")
        placeNameLabel.text = "No place selected"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Below another way of writing the above code:

```
import UIKit
import GooglePlacePicker

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var placeNameLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func placePicker(_ sender: Any) {
        let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: nil)
        let placePicker = GMSPlacePickerViewController(config: config)

        placePicker.delegate = self

        present(placePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

extension ViewController : GMSPlacePickerViewControllerDelegate {
    func placePicker(_ viewController: GMSPlacePickerViewController, didPick place: GMSPlace) {
        viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Place name \(place.name)")
        placeNameLabel.text = place.name
    }

    func placePicker(_ viewController: GMSPlacePickerViewController, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        // In your own app you should handle this better, but for the demo we are just going to log
        // a message.
        NSLog("An error occurred while picking a place: \(error)")
    }

    func placePickerDidCancel(_ viewController: GMSPlacePickerViewController) {
        // Dismiss the place picker, as it cannot dismiss itself.
        viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        print("No place selected")
        placeNameLabel.text = "No place selected"
    }
}
```